# JavaScript JSON.parse, find unexpect token position

Tags: javascript, json, parsing, token

Anybody have a clue how to find the unexpected token?

I am using JavaScript JSON.parse to parse a **string** with \" escape.

The problem is my program is complaining about there is a unexpect token.

How can i find out where is that token in the string? like line number or column number?

Thank you so much

Errors

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token 
message: "Unexpected token  "
stack: "SyntaxError: Unexpected token   ↵    at Object.parse (native)↵    at                      FileReader.eval (eval at evaluate (unknown source), <anonymous>:2:6)↵    at FrameMirror.evaluate (native)↵    at Object.evaluate (<anonymous>:415:28)↵    at Object.InjectedScript._evaluateOn (<anonymous>:668:39)↵    at Object.InjectedScript._evaluateAndWrap (<anonymous>:607:52)↵    at Object.InjectedScript.evaluateOnCallFrame (<anonymous>:718:21)↵    at FileReader.r.onload >(http://*******/uploadwave/uploadwave.js:77:37)"
get stack: function () { [native code] }
set stack: function () { [native code] }
__proto__: Error
```

Comment: Most likely your JSON is invalid or you are using JSON.parse incorrectly. Could you give us the target code?

Comment: http://jsonlint.com/ <-- this will point you to the exact character.

Comment: @m59: Not always. But it will at least tell you in which line the problem is.

Comment: It almost looks looks like the invalid token is some weird white space or unprintable character. The `\"` escape sequence is valid, so that's not it.

Comment: @c0d3junk13 the target code is a super long book in xml format. I mean should bexml format.

Comment: @FelixKling, I think so, but i have removed most of the invisible character by replace "\n\r" into a "".

Comment: @m59 Jsonlint can not pass array...for some reason...